# Union в комбинации с join дает некорректные результаты

Tags: sql, hive

Пытаюсь в Hive объединить данные из двух таблиц. Идея в том что есть два разных идентификатора, и нужно объединить записи из этих таблиц так чтобы совпадал хотя бы один идентификатор. Упрощенно, код выглядит так:

```
       WITH a AS(
          SELECT column1, column2, id1, id2, column3
          FROM table1
       ),
       
       b AS(
          SELECT id1, id2, column4, column5
          FROM table2
       )
       
       SELECT column1, column2, a.id1, a.id2, column3, b.id1, b.id2, column4, column5
       FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
       ON a.id1 = b.id1

       UNION

       SELECT column1, column2, a.id1, a.id2, column3, b.id1, b.id2, column4, column5
       FROM a LEFT JOIN b 
       ON a.id2 = b.id2
```

Запрос работает, но на выходе таблица некорректна. Я ожидаю увидеть в ней 9 столбцов как и в обеих объединяемых таблицах, но столбцов только 7 - не хватает идентификаторов из таблицы b, причем тип и вид данных последних столбцов не совпадает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прогонял уже много раз с незначительными вариациями, всегда примерно такой результат. Есть стойкое ощущение что где то нарушается порядок join'ов/union'ов, но по тому что нашел в интернете сначала должны выполняться именно джойны, а уже потом юнион, и результат приведенного кода должен был быть корректным. Подскажите, возможно не вижу какой то очевидной ошибки.

Comment: 1) зачем вам юнион? не достаточно объединить условия в джойн через OR ? 2) имена столбцов в id1,id2 дублируются. Алиас таблицы к результирующему столбцу отношения не имеет. напишите `b.id2 as b_id2` например.

Comment: В хайве сджойнить условиями через OR невозможно, выдает ошибку. Про такой вариант я и сам подумал в первую очередь, но оказалось что нельзя так.

Про названия столбцов - спасибо, попробую!

Comment: как-то сложно представить СУБД, которая не умеет OR в выражениях. а И и отрицание умеет? )

Comment: Думаю, что это типичная проблема неаккуратности плюс непонимания того, как работает используемый клиент. Ну-ка попробуй вот так: `SELECT column1, column2, a.id1 AS aid1, a.id2 AS aid2, column3, b.id1 AS bid1, b.id2 AS bid2, column4, column5`. Кстати, если получишь корректный результат - срочно меняй клиента, он некорректен.

Comment: Условия OR в хайве в целом конечно поддерживаются, но не разрешены в джойнах. Тут например описание проблемы, отсюда же взял вариант с использованием UNION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742889/or-not-supported-currently-in-join-error-in-hive

Проблема действительно была в некорректных алиасах, после исправления все заработало корректно. Спасибо за ответы!